# how to estimate Energy Consumed in trc20 transfer transactions

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tron, tronweb

Sometimes Energy Consumed in tron transactions became half!

In this moment, its`345 Bandwidth` and `29,631 Energy`

But sometimes it became `345 Bandwidth` and `14,815 Energy`

How to estimate transfer Gas fee in moment?

(If getChainParameters api helping, tell me how? because I don't understand how to use it to estimate fee)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tron API to estimate fee:
https://developers.tron.network/reference/triggerconstantcontract

> For estimating energy: use triggerconstantcontract to call the non-readonly method of the contract, and the energy_used field in the returned value is the energy consumption. Therefore, the fee_limit of the transaction can be set to energy_used x energy unit price

Answer (score 0):

If you possess only one TRC20 token in your account, the deducted energy cost for transactions is only half the actual amount. For instance, if the sender lacks any USDT in their account and attempts to transfer the maximum amount, the energy cost incurred would be..